# Scrolling in listview,builder is slow in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am using listview. builder inside singlechildScrollview but when I am scrolling through listview it is lagging. what is the solution to prevent lagging effect?

This issue is in release mode itself, so how to remove this lagging problem?

```
body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          deviceSize.width > 768 ? SideLayout() : Container(),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: deviceSize.width > 768 ? 50 : 2.5,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: deviceSize.width > 768
                        ? EdgeInsets.all(8)
                        : EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5.0),
                    child: Container(
                      width: deviceSize.width > 768 ? 780 : deviceSize.width,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          LatestButton(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: deviceSize.width > 768 ? 20 : 0,
                  ),
                  ListView.builder(
                    padding: deviceSize.width > 768 ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 120, right: 200) : EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: 9,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return PollCard();
                      }),
                  
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Could you please add code of PollCard() widget? I have tried by replacing PollCard(), LatestButton & SideLayout with container and its working fine without lagging. So there could be something in those widgets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this in your ListView.builder

```
primary: false,
```

Don't use

```
physics = NeverScrollableScrollPhysics();
```

Comment: This is really helpful, I am still using NeverScrollableScrollPhysics which is fine because I have been using this list inside another list. I have also used ShrinkWrap = true. This parameter primary=false really improves performance.

Answer (score 0):

I got your issue. This is not because you have trouble in your code.
It's because your shaders are not precompiled. Skia engine performs
better when shader's are precompiled. That will help you to avoid those janky frames.

Do As Following

```
flutter run --profile --cache-sksl --purge-persistent-cache
```

Perform transitions and animation as much as possible in your app.  Then **PRESS M** to save shader file eg. name.sksl.json

Run to build your app with compiled shaders

Android:

```
flutter build apk --bundle-sksl-path flutter_01.sksl.json
```

Ios:

```
flutter build ios --bundle-sksl-path flutter_01.sksl.json
```

Test release apk in your device.

I hope This will help you.